# Passing a Param to System.EventHandler in c#

Tags: c#

Since google has failed me for the past 5-10 minutes I have a quick question. I wish to pass a param value into a function that I call from a button.click Event Handler. The event is currently added using

```
MyButton.Click = new System.EventHandler(MyButton_click);
```

But I want the function to recieve:

```
private void MyButton_click(int ID)
{
...
}
```

How can I change my EventHandler declaration so that this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Button.Click` is defined as it is, and there is no way to change it. However,

```
myButton.Click += delegate { MyButton_click(1); }
```

will do the job.

Comment: lambda version: `myButton.Click += (sender, e) => MyButton_Click(1);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CommandArgument property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) and then cast a sender in your event handler to a Button type to get the CommandArgument value